# Cron job cant finish processing urls

Tags: php, curl, cron

I have cron pointed to `.txt` file and it has the following lines:

```
curl "http://www.website.com/&sample1&reset=0"; 
curl "http://www.website.com/&sample2&reset=0"; 
curl "http://www.website.com/&sample3&reset=0"; 
// [...]
curl "http://www.website.com/&sampleN&reset=0";
```

I have about 40-50 lines in one TXT file.
How to make CRON JOB to do one line at a time, not all in once?

Comment: I'm not sure I got what you meant. What does "to do one line at a time" means?

Comment: By the looks of it you could almost use a for loop if only part of the url is different.

Comment: It should already do it one after another. Are you sure it doesn't ?
Are all those lines are similar (differ only by some parameter) ?

Comment: all lines only differ by parameter. but for some reason it wont process them to the end.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put all those urls to the file urls.txt and make a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for url in `cat urls.txt`; do
 curl $url
done
```

If all looks so similar than you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 100`; do
 curl http://www.website.com/&sample${i}&reset=0
done
```

Comment: he want to use cron job so where is your PHP here ?

Comment: what `seq 1 100` does? is it limitation to 100 lines?

Comment: it's just as a example to do iteration from 1 to 100..
You want to do this by PHP ?? I don't see the point to use php for such of simple CRON job. You don't need php to use curl

Comment: Can 2nd variant be saved in  .txt and point cron to this file?

Comment: You can attach whatever you like to cron. Make it `chmod +x` and it'll work.

Comment: Ok. I probably know now why it runs paraler in your case. Please tell what exactly do you mean by "point cron to a file"

Comment: how the urls should be divided if I use variant 1?

Comment: I fetch data from another website into my database, it is possible their server is not always responding quickly. So I want cron job to finish all requests one by one, so it finishes one request completely before it sends another request.

Comment: Ok. The question is about your cron configuration.

Comment: in cron job settings I have "php /home/public_html/cron/1.txt"

Comment: then 1.txt has the following: curl "url1"; curl "url2";

Comment: since I have over 40 lines I set up to run another cron job in 30 min, it is more than enough to finish 1st cron job

Comment: ok.. so just put the code above to a file. Let say `hit_urls.sh` make `chmod +x hit_urls.sh` add change cron config to `"/home/whatever/you/like/hit_urls.sh"` without `php` in it !

Comment: mine. second from my example if you wish to do 100 hits or adjust the values as you need

Comment: 2nd example wont work, values differ, it has to be urls, then how to do it? point to another .txt file with urls? how urls should be divided?

Comment: than use first example where urls.txt is your file - put there all URLs you like one per line. You can put there full path as well to this file.

Comment: No. Just one per line

Comment: works! if I want to have 3000 lines or more, will it process it? or I need to create another cron job

Comment: Glad to hear that. You can put as much as you want. But remember that there can be a situation when it'll take to long to finish all and it'll overlap then.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$file = fopen(..., 'r');
```

to open your file, then use

```
$line = fgets ($file);
```

to read a single line from that file.